# How to login with Facebook javascript SDK in hybrid HTML5 based application

Tags: ios, facebook, html, authentication, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building an hybrid app for Android and iPhone based on html5. I want to implement in my app login with Facebook. All the Html on the application are a local on the device; I don't have a server so I want to save the token from Facebook in the local storage. Is it possible to implement this  with Facebook javascript SDK?

I tried the code from Facebook developer site:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked. -->

<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get the following error in browser console:

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains. "

Comment: Tobias, did you ever get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your apps config.xml you should have something like `<access origin="*">`